# Trigger double click function, and holding on the last click AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouse, double-click

I have a game, where my character moves to the right or left, with a MOUSE_DOWN eventlistener. the character jumps, with a DOUBLE_CLICK eventlistener. 
I want it so that if the player double clicks **and holds down on the last click**, then the character jumps and moves. 
As it is now, the jumping function only works if the player double clicks and release the mouse. 
Is this possible in any way??

So just to make it a little clearer. When the player double clicks and releases, the character shall jump where he stands. This already works.
But if the player double clicks and holds down, then both the jump function and move function should be triggered.

Thanks in advance!

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var character:Character = new Character;
    public var world:World = new World;

    var moveRight:Boolean = false;
    var moveLeft:Boolean = false;
    var jumping:Boolean = false;

    var moveSpeed:Number = 1;
    var orgMoveSpeed:Number = 1;
    var accSpeed:Number = 0.6;
    var maxMoveSpeed:Number = 20;
    var gravity:Number = 1;
    var orgGrav:Number = 1;
    var gravAcc:Number = 0.6
    var maxFallSpeed:Number = 15;
    var jumpPower:Number = 15;
    var jumpGrav:Number = 0.6;
    var orgJumpPower:Number =15;
    public function Main() {
        // constructor code
        addChild(world)
        addChild(character)

        stage.doubleClickEnabled=true;
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, moveFunction)
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMoveFunction)
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, jumpFunction)
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveWorld)
    }
    function moveFunction(m:MouseEvent)
    {
    //If the player clicks on right side of the screen, the player moves right.. etc.
        if(mouseX>stage.stageWidth/2)
        {
            moveRight = true
        }else{
            moveLeft = true
        }
    }
    function stopMoveFunction(m:MouseEvent)
    {
        moveLeft = false;
        moveRight = false;
    }

    function jumpFunction(m:MouseEvent)
    {
        if(hitGroundCol)
        {
            jumping=true;
        }
    }

    function moveWorld(e:Event)
    {

//_______MOVE FUNCTION _____________________
        if (moveRight)
        {
            world.x -= moveSpeed
            moveSpeed += accSpeed
            character.OddSlugViz.rotation += moveSpeed
        }else if (moveLeft)
        {
            world.x += moveSpeed
            moveSpeed += accSpeed
            character.OddSlugViz.rotation -= moveSpeed
        }else{
            moveSpeed = orgMoveSpeed;
        }

        if (moveSpeed>maxMoveSpeed)
        {
            moveSpeed = maxMoveSpeed;
        }
//_________Jump_________________

        if (jumping)
        {
            world.y += jumpPower
            jumpPower -= jumpGrav
            if (jumpPower<1)
            {
                jumping = false;
                jumpPower = orgJumpPower;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to track a single click even and start a timer or a timeout and if another mouse down event occurs within a time limit (100 ms? you'd have to test to see how natural you want it), then do the event.. that way you can track the mouse is being held down, and that it's a double click, without using the double click event.

Comment: Great! Just one thing, I forgot to add that it was a air for android project, but do you think I still could use this method??

Comment: I think it should work yeah, might need a bit longer on the timeout or timer since I think it would be quicker to double click than to tap twice.